# cleaning phonenumbers using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have the following composition of phonenumbers where 33 is the area code:

```
+331234567
+3301234567
00331234567
003301234567
0331234567
033-123-456-7
0033.1234567
```

where Im expecting only `331234567`

What I have tried to clean those numbers using `R`

```
R::tidyverse::str_replace_all(c("+331234567", "033-123-456-7", "0033.1234567"), pattern = "[^0-9.]", replacement = "") removing non-numeric characters
R::tidyverse::str_replace_all("0331234567", pattern = "^0", replacement = "") removing the leading 0
R::tidyverse::str_replace_all("00331234567", pattern = "^00", replacement = "") removing the leading 00
```

my question is how to remove the zeros in between: 33`0`1234567 or 0033`0`1234567 or +33`0`1234567 or 033`0`1234567

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("^(?:00?|\\+)330?|\\W", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypWcpY/3). See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Pj0EHG).

If there can be more `0`s after `33` before the number you need to extract, replace `0?` with `0*`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:00?|\+)` - `00`, `0` or `+`
- `330?` - `33` or `330`
- `|` - or
- `\W` - any non-word char.

Comment: amazing!! Especially providing examples in R and regex. thank you

Comment: would it be easy to expand that regex for varying  area code, lets say 34,35?

Comment: @Googme Yes, replace `33` with `3[3-5]`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypWcpY/4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^\+?0*3*0*|[^\s\d]`

Pattern explanation:

`^` - match beginning of the string

`\+?` - match `+` literally, zero or one time.

`0*` - match zero or more `0`

`3*` - match zero or more `3`

`|` - alternation

`[^\s\d]` - negated character class - match any character other from whitespace and digit (you could remove `\s` if you handle one number at a time, it just prevents from matching newline in demo)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZRthy/2)

It will match unwanted parts separately. First part will clean beginning of a number if it starts with `+` or `0`, second part will clean non-digits inside the number.